# Is this a LFI vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, lfi, local-file-inclusion

I'm playing with uploads, so I'm wondering if this route is safe to use, because if you somehow break off from the `md5` function path, then you can control the path (if in TypeScript null byte is a thing).

Note: `Snyk` denotes this as an `LFI` issue!

Finally, my question is this vulnerability or the `Snyk` just evaluates this way (because of variable names)? And also, is there any other way except the infamous null byte to bypass extensions?

The pseudocode is written in TS.

```
// ? This is pseudocode and it is not 100% valid.

router.post("/profile", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (img.mimetype === "image/png" || img.mimetype === "image/jpeg") {
    if (img.size < 1048576) {
      var user = { userName: "UserControlledInput", password: "password", email: "email" }
      if (user) {
        let imgName = md5('prefix' + user.userName);
        let imgPath = "assets/avatars/" + imgName + "." + img.mimetype.split("/")[1]
        fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../jekyll/_site/" + imgPath), img.buffer, async (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.warn("Error:", err);
          } else {
            user.save_to_database()
            return res.send({ message: "Success!" });
          };
        })
      } else {
        res.send({ message: "First you must login, Not allowed!"})
      };
    } else {
      return res.send({ message: "Not allowed, files larger then 1MB." });
    };
  };
});
```

Comment: How is the output of your `md5` function - BTW, _don't use MD5_, just don't, there's no reason to do so, use something modern - encoded? If it's treated directly as UTF-8 or UCS-2/UTF-16 or some such, there is a risk here. Not a huge one - MD5 is broken but AFAIK nobody has a feasible attack that allows finding a partially-constrained preimage that hashes to an arbitrary digest - but it is in theory possible for the file name start with a bunch of "../" triplets. If it's encoded as hex or similar, though, that can't happen.

Comment: @CBHacking - I forgot to mention that the `md5` function is a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5). You can try it yourself and it's a user-controlled field, so for the example it would be "e70503706bc80fbf2d346531baa4f3bc". 
---
Yeah, you are right. I should use something different, but I thought it was only a filename. What would you recommend to use? (just encoding or hashing)
--
Anyway, appreciate your response.

Comment: OK, hex-encoded, so that's not a problem. Still recommend something from the SHA2 or SHA3 family. Since you don't really need it for security per se you could go with the shortest 224-bit (28-byte) digests, though usually people opt for 256. It's not even that I expect MD5's cryptographic weaknesses to be relevant here (even without the hex encoding); it's just an obsolete algorithm. Also, any security scanner you run on your code will yell at you about it.

Comment: `Synk` evaulates it that way because user input is somehow used to construct a local filepath. I don't see any way how a malicious user can manipulate that to include an actual local file path. Does not look vulnerable (to LFI) to me.